# Split Number into high and low words in C

Tags: c, labview

I want to send data from Labview FPGA to a C function using the C API. To get the data transmitted synchronized I do the following:

1) Input:

- 3x I16 values
- 1x U16 value

2) In two steps I pack these 4 values into a U64 using the join number function in Labview (it does hi.lo). So it is basically:

```
((I16.I16).(I16.U16))
(   U32   .   U32   )
         U64
```

3) Now this U64 value gets transferred to the C function where it should be unpacked like this:

```
         U64
(   U32   .   U32   )
((I16.I16).(I16.U16))
```

Now I wonder how the unpacking would be handled in C. Is there something like the "Split Number" function in Labview? How do I make sure all the parts get the right data type assigned?

Comment: Not sure if this works: `short * U16 = (short *) &U64; // Access each number like U16[2]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there isn't. You generally do this type of thing using bitwise operations, mainly shifts and masks:

```
const uint64_t incoming = 0xfeedcafebabef00d;
const int16_t  first  = (int16_t) (incoming >> 48);
const int16_t  second = (int16_t) ((incoming >> 32) & 0xffff);
const int16_t  third  = (int16_t) ((incoming >> 16) & 0xffff);
const uint16_t fourth = incoming & 0xffff;
```

This of course assumes the endianness is proper everywhere, and will set `first` to `0xfeed` (-275 in decimal) and so on.

As a general observation, the amount of actual code needed to do each extraction is minimal, which might explain why there is no general-purpose function to do this: you don't need one.

You can of course write one anyway, if you feel like it:

```
uint16_t extractU16(uint64_t bits, uint8_t lsbIndex)
{
  return (uint16_t) ((bits >> lsbIndex) & 0xffff);
}
```

Given that, you can rewrite the above as:

```
const int16_t  first  = (int16_t) extractU16(incoming, 48);
const int16_t  second = (int16_t) extractU16(incoming, 32);
const int16_t  third  = (int16_t) extractU16(incoming, 16);
const uint16_t fourth = extractU16(incoming, 0);
```

We can further improve (?) by doing an `extractS16()` that returns `int16_t` of course, to allow dropping the cast, but I won't bother. :)

Comment: Ahh, you found the paren :)

Comment: Originally, there was a missing parentheses in `second = (int16_t) (incoming >> 32) & 0xffff);`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Ah, cool, thanks. I think I never saw that. :)

Comment: It's working fine. Thanks a lot! I like your sample variable by the way :D

Answer (score 1):

There is another way, without shifts and masks. Assuming correct endianess:

```
#pragma pack(1)
union abc {
    struct u {
        int16_t a;
        int16_t b;
        int16_t c;
        uint16_t d;
     } u16;
     uint64_t u64;
 } datum;

 datum.u64 = XXXX; /* Number you got from LV */
 datum.u16.a /* first of the the numbers */
```

use it like that:

```
  datum.u64=0x112233445566ull;

  printf("%x\n", datum.u16.a);
  printf("%x\n", datum.u16.b);
  printf("%x\n", datum.u16.c);
  printf("%x\n", datum.u16.d);
```